# Challenge: Using forEach

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am having a lot of trouble with the syntax and application of forEach functions. Please help!

Recreate the function droids from the previous challenge, but instead of using a FOR loop, use the built-in forEach method.

Previous challenge:

```
function droids(arr) {
  let result = '';
 for (let str of arr) {
      if (str  === 'Droids') {
       return 'Found Droids!';
    }
}
       return `These are not the droids you're looking for.`;
}


// Uncomment these to check your work! 
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"] 
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"] 
console.log(droids(starWars)) // should log: "Found Droids!"
console.log(droids(thrones)) // should log: "These are not the droids you're looking for."
```

This is what I have:

```
function droids(arr) {
  let result = "";
arr.forEach(item => 
console.log(result))
if (result = "Droids") {
return "Found Droids!"
} else {
  return "These are not the droids you're looking for.";
}};
```

Comment: You can't use `foreach` to return from an outer function, so it isn't a good fit here. `foreach` should really be used when you just want to carry out simple side effects over a list, like printing or modifying an outer state.

Comment: find() or indexOf() are better suited here

Comment: Proper indentation would make this so much more readable

Comment: Don't just swap operators... `=` should be `==` or `===`

Comment: Why is the `return "These are not..."` _in_ the loop?

Comment: The only way I can think of is before set the forEach loops, let found = false; Then set it found = true in the forEach if the condition is met. As others have said there are better ways than using forEach, I wonder if that’s the point of the challenge.

Comment: Whoever marked this as duplicate is a bit off here with the linked question. There's more than just breaking out of a forEach loop going on here.

Comment: Yeah, the linked dup is *a* possible solution, but this is certainly a distinct question from that one at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a value from the callback in a `forEach` loop, so you need to rely on side effects - give `result` a default value indicating you didn't find `Droids` and then set it to `"Found Droids!"` only if you do match `Droids` somewhere in the array:

```js
function droids(arr) {
  let result = "These are not the droids you're looking for.";
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (item === "Droids") {
      result = "Found Droids!";
    }
  });
  return result
}

// Uncomment these to check your work! 
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Droids", "Rey", "Kylo"]
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"]
console.log(droids(starWars)) // should log: "Found Droids!"
console.log(droids(thrones)) // should log: "These are not the droids you're looking for."
```

Comment: Your solution is more concise than mine. No `foundDroids` needed. Only change the `result` if the droids are found. Simple.

Comment: @daddygames yeah, KISS is my middle name :)

Comment: You can also do something like `arr.forEach(item => item === "Droids" && (result = "Found Droids!"));` if you want to slightly complicate it for the sake of being stylish and hip.

Comment: Oh wow, duh!! This is super helpful, thanks : D

Comment: @JacobGray see my previous comment :)

Answer (score 0):

`if (result = "Droids")` This does not check, it assigns. You want to use `==`.

You don't want to return from inside the `forEach` method. You need to assign the result and return that result after processing the records.

Be sure to compare the item to the string value you're looking for.

```js
function droids(arr) {
  let result = "";
  let foundDroids = false;
  arr.forEach(item => {
    if (!foundDroids) {
      if (item == "Droids") {
        result = "Found Droids!"
        foundDroids = true;
      } else {
        result = "These are not the droids you're looking for.";
      }
    }
  });
  return result;
};

const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Droids", "Rey", "Kylo"] 
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"] 
console.log(droids(starWars)) 
console.log(droids(thrones))
```

I would prefer to use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like so:

```js
function droids(arr) {
  if (arr.includes("Droids")) {
    return "Found Droids!";
  } else {
    return "These are not the droids you're looking for.";
  }
};

const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Droids", "Rey", "Kylo"] 
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"] 
console.log(droids(starWars)) 
console.log(droids(thrones))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just not use `Array.prototype.forEach`, but instead use `Array.prototype.some` to determine whether the item was present or not.

The `some` has the same signature as the `forEach` method, except you need to return a boolean. If you return `true`, the method will short-circuit and stop iteration immediately upon finding a match. It is better for performance.

```js
const search = (items, target, foundText, notFoundText) =>
  items.some(item => item === target) ? foundText : notFoundText;

const droids = (names) => search(names, 'Droids', 'Found Droids!',
  "These are not the droids you're looking for.");

// Uncomment these to check your work! 
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"]
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"]
console.log(droids(starWars)) // "Found Droids!"
console.log(droids(thrones))  // "These are not the droids you're looking for."
```

Since this is a primitive array, you could also use `Array.prototype.includes`.

```js
const search = (items, target, foundText, notFoundText) =>
  items.includes(target) ? foundText : notFoundText;

const droids = (names) => search(names, 'Droids', 'Found Droids!',
  "These are not the droids you're looking for.");

// Uncomment these to check your work! 
const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"]
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"]
console.log(droids(starWars)) // "Found Droids!"
console.log(droids(thrones))  // "These are not the droids you're looking for."
```

Comment: Not sure how well this answers the question, as OP was specifically asking how to do it with `forEach`

Comment: @JacobGray The method `Array.prototype.some` method is a modified version of `Array.prototype.forEach` that expected a boolean return value that can short-circuit if the return value is `true`. I updated the response to include a blurb.

Comment: My point more being that this appears to be a homework-style question, and if he were to use `some` or `includes`, he'd risk failing. Not sure how a question like this should be treated though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function droids(arr) {
  let result = '';
  arr.forEach(item => {
    item === "Droids" ? result = `Found Droids!` : result = `These are not the droids you're looking for.`
  });
  return result;
}

const starWars = ["Luke", "Finn", "Rey", "Kylo", "Droids"]
const thrones = ["Jon", "Danny", "Tyrion", "The Mountain", "Cersei"]
console.log(droids(starWars)) // should log: "Found Droids!"
console.log(droids(thrones)) // should log: "These are not the droids you're looking for."
```